# Existe limite de conexão simultânea SQLite PHP ?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel, sqlite

Atualmente uso Mysql no meu servidor com limite de 50 conexões simultâneas..
pensei em usar o SQL Server que por sua vez nao tem limite de conexão simultâneas  mas é muito caro!!..

Então pensei em usar SQLlite, mas gostaria de saber se existe algum limite de conexão simultâneas ou de armazenamento?

Comment: As decisões não pode ser assim, precisa ver seu problema, porque em tese o MySQL não tem limite, pode ter uma configuração, mas é só mudar. Por outro lado tem uma limitação prática, que eu duvido que seja tão baixa em qualquer máquina.

Comment: Mas então Maniero , no caso eu uso servidor compartilhado
e o host tem essas limitações.. de no minimo 25 conexões simultâneas.
e por exemplo: meu limite é de 50 conexões simultâneas e  eu tenho um script que primeiro faz 1 select (após 10,20 segundos) faz 1 insert, 2 select, 2 update
sendo assim abrindo 5 conexões , mesmo sendo rápido (em questão de milésimos).. tendo uma base de 200 usuários, com em torno de 100 deles logado ao mesmo tempo esta causando erro, pois se 11 usuários está online no mesmo instante da execução do script 11*5 = 55 conexões . . e o servidor já da erro

Comment: Bem simples, troque de hospedagem, bem menos traumático que trocar de banco de dados, e muito mais sensato por todos os pontos de vista possíveis.

Comment: O que você entende por "conexão"? Normalmente você não tem "conexão" com SQLite, afinal, nativamente ele não é um servidor.

Comment: E se é o mesmo script que faz tudo isso, por que ele demanda 5 conexões simultâneas? Não basta uma e executar todas as operações pela mesma conexão?

Comment: é @Maniero segui seu conselho e do colega Anderson e troquei de hospedagem e refiz o script de conexão, agora esta 100% vlw galera!